# QPen, value changing

Tags: c++, qt

I have to change color of QPen. Problem is the data which I loading have just two values 0 and 1. QPen have to have values from 0 to 255, I have to multiply value from file 255 times. I have another methode but it is not exactly functional. Is it possible to multiply values 255 times when I get 0,1 values from pixel?

```
    if (wert > max){
                max = wert;
            }

            }

        pen = QPen(QColor(max * 255, max * 255, max * 255));
        painter.setPen(pen);
        painter.drawPoint(i, j);
```

Comment: Yes, you can certainly use those two compare routines within a loop that functions 255 times (although you might use `if x < 0.5 ... setColor(white) ... else setColor(black)` )

Comment: how should the loop looks like

Comment: A loop is a pretty basic programming structure.  It almost sounds like you've never ever touched C++ (or any other programming language) before? If that is the case, I'd strongly recommend you take a class in how C/C++ works. That would be time well spent.  If you don't do that, you are going to have a whole bunch of other issues in your program, I guarantee it.  Is this for a personal Internet of Things (IOT) project?  It doesn't sound like a homework assignment.

Comment: actually I am making ray casting rendering program. And we dont have good understood each other.  Here is a, rest of, code. I have to somewhere add, converting statement to convert binary data form volume file to 0-255 standard from QColor.


m_Volume->voxel(x, y, z).getValue();
 

 for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
  for (int j = 0; i < y; j++){
   for (int k = 0; i < z; k++){
    painter.drawPoint(x, y,QColor();
   
   }
  }
 }

  m_Ui->label->setPixmap(map);

Comment: best is to update your original posting with the new code.  Its much easier to read that way.

Comment: Your code could could be simplified to `QPen pen(x == 1 ? Qt::white : Qt::black);`. 1 line instead of 7 lines.

Comment: I changed it, a lot actually. This works 100 pro.

Comment: If you are filling an image pixel-by-pixel, it might be ore efficient to use `QImage` and only transforming the finished image into a `QPixmap`.

If your origin colors mean "background" and "foreground", you could also look into filling the image with target "background" and only setting the pixels that have "foreground"

Comment: I have to use drawPoint, because I have to load from file this specific value